# Launcher icon for PhoneGap reverts to stock one

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I am facing a truly unique issue - basically I am building locally: `cordova build android` and have added all the custom icons for m,h,xh,xxhdpi densities to `www/res/icon/android/` folder. When I try to install the "debug APK" on my Android tablet, it even shows the custom launcher icon on the top-left of the installation dialog. However, the launcher icon in the installed app in the drawer (grid) shows the stock PhoneGap icon. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default icon? `<icon src="www/res/icon.png" />`

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.0.0/config_ref/images.html

Comment: Yes, I do. I have a 192x192 icon at that location (www/res/icon.png)

Comment: Like I said, the custom icon show up in the installation dialog but reverts to stock one in the app drawer.

Comment: UPDATE: I resolved this by cleaning and rebuilding the phonegap project. Just some funky cache issues.